# referencing "include" file in vxworks *.wpj file

Tags: embedded, vxworks

Is it possible to add a reference (e.g. "include" file) in a vxworks .wpj file?

The idea is similar to how one can include <stdio.h> in a c++ source file.  I would like to have a file called "project_files.txt" (or whatever) that I can list my c++ source files.  Then I can reference my c++ source files from within the vxworks .wpj file by "including" this "project_files.txt" (instead of listing the c++ source files directly inside of the vxworks .wpj file.